# Spring Security & CAS - Backup login page in case of CAS failure?

Tags: spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I have an application that connects to a CAS server, allows the user to do the CAS/SSO login, and then redirects them to the application's home page. Simple enough.

The problem is that CAS is relatively new to my organization and as of today, we only have it set up on one server. So, if the server becomes unreachable for any reason, the application can no longer be accessed as the CAS login page will not load.

What I would like is for my application to be able to detect
a) the CAS server is unreachable after a reasonable number of retries
b) subsequently redirect the user to the non-CAS/SSO login page and use the basic Spring Security config that is in place using LDAP

I don't see anything in the Spring documentation for this particular scenario. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try extending `CasAuthenticationEntryPoint`. Entry points in Spring Security are the things that determine where to go when authentication is necessary.

```
public LocalLoginFallbackCasAuthenticationEntryPoint 
    extends CasAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    protected String createRedirectUrl(final String serviceUrl) {
        if ( prevailingCircumstancesMandate() ) {
            return "/our/legacy/login/page";
        } else {
            // go to CAS, like normal
            return super.createRedirectUrl(serviceUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

And then configure in your `HttpSecurity` object:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(myCustomEntryPoint());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Josh. I've been exploring it since yesterday and where I'm stuck is the "prevailing circumstances" part. The CAS entry point URL I'm returning is expected to be unreachable, so I don't get any response back. I'm unable to figure out how to identify that. It's only when I know that that URL is unreachable, that I will pass in my custom entry point. I will keep exploring. Suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: So, in short, you can't. Once you redirect to another service, it is up to that service to handle that request. What could can do relatively easily is maybe think about it from a service discovery standpoint. For example, "prevailing circumstances" might just be a configuration property: e.g. should.we.redirect.to.cas=true. Then, perhaps you could have automation monitor the CAS server for 500 and 400 status counts, and once that count goes over a certain threshold, the automation switches the configuration value for a period of time and then switches it back.